# Trouble migrating a MySQL database to MS SQL 2012 using the migration assistant

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a MySQL server database to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.  I converted the schema and synchronized the databases, but when I try to do the migration, it doesn't work and I get this when it's done:
[image]

I don't think it even tried to migrate anything.  I have no idea what I could have missed.  Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have you tried to follow [these steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313125.aspx)?

Comment: I did indeed follow those steps.

Comment: I would try to start over again and see if you process breaks on the same steps as before. It is easy to miss a setting somewhere that breaks stuff in later steps.

Comment: I've run it about seven or eight times and the results are the same.  Are there any other third party tools that might accomplish the same task?

Comment: Can you build the table schema, create that, then export/import the data?  These tools never seem to work.

Comment: tommy_o, the tool did seem to create the tables on the target server.